# Visual Studio Code Typescript avoid parameters on new line

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Angular project on Visual Studio Code and I getting one annoying format document setting on Typescript files where it breaks parameters to a new line:

Before formatting (alt+shift+f):

```
this.opportunityId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('opportunityid');
this.opportunityTermVendorId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('vendorid');
this.opportunityTermVendorAssetId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('assetid');
this.opportunityTermCollateralId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('collateralid');
```

After formatting (alt+shift+f):

```
this.opportunityId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('opportunityid');
this.opportunityTermVendorId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('vendorid');
this.opportunityTermVendorAssetId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get(
  'assetid'
);
this.opportunityTermCollateralId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get(
  'collateralid'
);
```

I have word wrap turned off but I still tried to set it to a bigger word wrap column value. See my current settings override

```
{
   "git.confirmSync": false,
   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
   "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
   "editor.formatOnSave": true,
   "prettier.singleQuote": true,
   "editor.wordWrapColumn": 180
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me `"prettier.printWidth": 180` didn't work, but it turns out the latest version of prettier doesn't have the "prettier" part at the beginning of each property.

So in `.prettierrc` I now have `"printWidth": 180` which fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_word-wrap-settings-redesign)

> editor.wordWrap: "off" - Lines will never wrap.
>   editor.wordWrap: "on" - Lines will wrap at viewport width.
>   editor.wordWrap: "wordWrapColumn" - Lines will wrap at the value of editor.wordWrapColumn. editor.wordWrap: "bounded" - Lines will wrap at the minimum of viewport width and the value of editor.wordWrapColumn.

you should set:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 180
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help, after messing around a little more I figured out that the extension called "Prettier" that comes with "Angular Essentials" was causing the issue. I just had to add "prettier.printWidth": 160

Comment: Not working for me as of the current version. By default, its set to off - and still i see the same behavior. Even after i override dafult behavior with the settings you provided - i still see the same weird new lines after formatting. If you have updated info - please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209641/tslint-in-vs-code-formatting-new-lines-before-arguments

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the extension called "Prettier" that comes with "Angular Essentials" was causing the issue. I just had to add "prettier.printWidth": 160 to the settings.

Comment: I've end up with the same. However, placing `"prettier.printWidth": 160` to the settings give no effect on the behavior.