# Prettier in VS Code formatting (new lines before arguments)

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint, prettier

I'm using [Angular Essentials by John Papa](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials) - in particular, Tslint and Prettier. For some reason, it transforms this code

```
this.rM.hA = this.rM.startHA + 2 * diffX * 360 / size;
this.rM.vA = Math.max(Math.min(this.rM.startVA + 2 * diffY * 180 / size, 90), -90);
```

into this

```
this.rM.hA =
  this.rM.startHA + 2 * diffX * 360 / size;
this.rM.vA = Math.max(
  Math.min(
    this.rM.startVA + 2 * diffY * 180 / size,
    90
  ),
  -90
);
```

How can i avoid it? I've tried to play with tslint.json settings:

> "max-line-length": [true, 165]

But that one does not affect in my case.

EDIT: as following the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939118/visual-studio-code-typescript-avoid-parameters-on-new-line) I've tried to set both `"prettier.printWidth"` and `"editor.wordWrap"`, but none of them helped. I've removed `max-line-length`, as suggested by @ConnorsFan, and my current Workspace Settings (which should override Users Settings, right?) is

> {
>   "prettier.printWidth": 180,
>   "editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
>   "editor.wordWrapColumn": 180 
>   }

EDIT2: it appears, problem is caused by Prettier extension (comes as dependency for Angular Essentials). Now the problem is narrowed to realize, why `"prettier.printWidth": 180` is not working. I've opened an issue https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3228

PS: The names have been changed to protect the innocent. (c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939118/visual-studio-code-typescript-avoid-parameters-on-new-line   The prettier extension might be the problem.  There is a solution there:  "prettier.printWidth": 160

Comment: @Mark Hm.. cant make it works for me. I've checked the default settings, and it says `"editor.wordWrap": "off"` - but still i face the same behavior. I've tried to override that setting as said in the link you mentioned - but it seems to have zero effect on the settings, i'm still receiving those weird newlines.

Comment: Did you try disabling `max-line-length` completely, and then restarting Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Just tried that - still the same. Its behavior is kinda weird: some of the lines are fine, but others are still "blown". All of them are less than 180 characters (i've set `"prettier.printWidth": 180` in the settings).

Comment: Are you sure that it is caused by tslint? Can you disabled it?

Comment: @ConnorsFan very nice suggestion! I've disabled whole John Papa's package - now Alt+Shift+F (hotkey for formatting) is not doing anything. Will play with tslint package separately... Nah, cant do that - its a dependency of the Angular Essentials itself.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Dammit, you're right! I've disabled AE (Angular Essentials) and enabled Tslint - not formatting works fine!

Comment: @ConnorsFan Oh, so its a Prettier extension who is blowing the lines! However, i'm wondering why `"prettier.printWidth": 180` is not doing its job.

Comment: Funny thing, both Prettier and Tslint are AE dependencies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`"prettier.printWidth": 120` worked for me with only having two javascript format extensions 'Prettier' & 'ESlint' in my vscode.